# Can the Microsoft Sync Framework work with only part of a database?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I have an application that has one central database and several local databases, and these must be periodically be synchronised.  The central database contains all the records (once sync has happened), but each local database only contains a subset of the data.  Can this be implemented with the Microsoft Sync Framework?  There would be some bespoke logic which determined which records were part of the subset.  We don't want to copy the whole database.

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework synchronizes per table and you can apply filters to what is synchronized as well.